# Contar valores coincidentes en un bucle

Tags: php, array, foreach

Tengo este array de valores de ejemplo, es algo más complejo, esto solo es un ejemplo y necesito correr ese array en un bucle.

```
$array_test=array("gren","green","red","red","green","blue");
```

Aquí lo que trato es de delimitar cuando valores se dan de cada condición, he tratado hacer de muchas formas, pero no conseguí nada, la única forma que es posible es creando 2 bucles para poner los valores en el otro con un array de cada elemento coincidente, pero hacer esto 2 veces no me parece adecuado, es poner más código y además aumentar la cantidad de procesos implicados, por eso la pregunta de cómo dentro del propio bucle hacer esto, saludos

```
foreach($array_test as $array_ts)  {

if($array_ts=="green") { /// contar número de elementos verdes /// }

if($array_ts=="red") { /// contar número de elementos rojos /// }

if($array_ts=="blue") { /// contar número de elementos azules /// }

}
```

Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda, un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Te sugiero esta solución:

```
<?php

$array_test=array("gren","green","red","red","green","blue");

$conteo=[];

foreach($array_test as $elemento){
    if(!isset($conteo[$elemento]))
        $conteo[$elemento]=0;
    $conteo[$elemento]++;
    echo '<div>'.$elemento.' : '.$conteo[$elemento].'</div>';
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($conteo,true).'</pre>';
```

Para obtener este resultado:

```
gren : 1
green : 1
red : 1
red : 2
green : 2
blue : 1
Array
(
    [gren] => 1
    [green] => 2
    [red] => 2
    [blue] => 1
)
```

Comment: El problema es que en mi version de php $conteo=[]; da error, hay alguna alternativa a esto para poder usar el ejemplo que me has puesto, muchas gracias de antemano por tu ayuda

Comment: Utiliza `$conteo=array();` que sería la equivalente para versiones de PHP anteriores

Comment: Muchas gracias, y una última pregunta, hay alguna forma de mostrar pero dentro del bucle ese número de elementos coincidentes, es decir no mostrar fuera del bucle el valor de cada uno, sino en cada vuelta y coincidencia mostrar el número que hay, gracias de nuevo

Comment: @Jean Puedes aprovechar cada iteración para ir mostrando el conteo de cada elemento. Modifico la respuesta para contemplar esta opción y de paso solucionar un pequeño error lógico